# Passing an iterator into a recursive call during an iteration in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust, borrow-checker

I'm writing a parser for a simple tree syntax. In doing so, I need to construct a tree from a series of tokens.

The meat of the code is currently mired with problems due to the borrower checker:

```rust
use std::vec;

fn parse_iter(token_iter: vec::IntoIter<Token>) -> Result<Vec<Node>, String>
{
    let mut nodes: Vec<Node> = vec![];
    let mut cur_node: Option<Node> = None;
    for token in token_iter {
        match token {
            Token::ParenOpen => {
                if let Some(mut node) = cur_node {
                    let mut children = parse_iter(token_iter)?;
                    node.children.append(&mut children);
                } else {
                    return Err("invalid token sequence".to_string());
                }
            }
            Token::ParenClose => {
                break;
            }
            Token::Name(name) => {
                let node = Node::new(name);
                nodes.push(node);
                cur_node = Some(node);
            }
            Token::Comma => {}
        }
    }
    Ok(nodes)
}


pub enum Token {
    ParenOpen,
    ParenClose,
    Comma,
    Name(String),
}

pub struct Node {
    pub name: String,
    pub children: Vec<Node>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new<'a>(name: String) -> Node {
        Node { name: name, children: vec![] }
    }
}
```

The resulting error messages:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/lib.rs:10:29
   |
10 |                 if let Some(mut node) = cur_node {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `token_iter`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:60
   |
3  | fn parse_iter(token_iter: vec::IntoIter<Token>) -> Result<(Vec<Node>, vec::IntoIter<Token>), String>
   |               ---------- move occurs because `token_iter` has type `std::vec::IntoIter<Token>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
7  |     for token in token_iter {
   |                  ----------
   |                  |
   |                  value moved here
   |                  help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&token_iter`
...
11 |                     let mut children_and_iter = parse_iter(token_iter)?;
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `node`
  --> src/lib.rs:23:33
   |
21 |                 let node = Node::new(name);
   |                     ---- move occurs because `node` has type `Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
22 |                 nodes.push(node);
   |                            ---- value moved here
23 |                 cur_node = Some(node);
   |                                 ^^^^ value used here after move
```

As you can see above, both `token_iter` and `cur_node` move illegally several times in this function, and I'm unsure of how wrap them correctly so as to satisfy the borrow checker. I've attempted using `RefCell<Rc<T>>`s but I eventually need to unwrap the values so these don't really help. Is what I'm attempting possible in Rust?

Comment: By the power of [Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/), stop do this in Rust.

Comment: Are there alternative data structures I can use to solve this problem? It’s an inherently recursive problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Right now it's hard to tell where to start fixing your issues since we don't have all the relevant imports/definitions.

Comment: I've edited the example of the problem. Hopefully it now provides enough context. One can arrive at the posted error messages if they run the code on https://play.rust-lang.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea to iterate `for token in token_iter` *and* trying to operate on `token_iter` inside the loop. Thus, I suggest to take `token_iter` as `&mut`, and iterate manually.

Additionally, having both `cur_node` and `nodes` seems redundant (if I am not mistaken, `cur_node` is essentially `nodes.last`). Thus, I'd try the following:

```
use std::vec;

fn parse_iter(token_iter: &mut vec::IntoIter<Token>) -> Result<(Vec<Node>, &mut vec::IntoIter<Token>), String>
{
    let mut nodes: Vec<Node> = vec![];
    while let Some(token)=token_iter.next() {
        match token {
            Token::ParenOpen => {
                if let Some(ref mut node) = nodes.last_mut() {
                    let mut children_and_iter = parse_iter(token_iter)?;
                    node.children.append(&mut children_and_iter.0);
                } else {
                    return Err("invalid token sequence".to_string());
                }
            }
            Token::ParenClose => {
                break;
            }
            Token::Name(name) => {
                nodes.push(Node::new(name));
            }
            Token::Comma => {}
        }
    }
    Ok((nodes, token_iter))
}


pub enum Token {
    ParenOpen,
    ParenClose,
    Comma,
    Name(String),
}

pub struct Node {
    pub name: String,
    pub children: Vec<Node>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new<'a>(name: String) -> Node {
        Node { name: name, children: vec![] }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just writing up a nearly identical solution that I arrived at after getting some help on the Rust Discord. Comforting that two folks led to similar conclusions!

BTW I've edited the question to remove the tuple return value as that was just another way at attempting to get around the borrow checker.